# How to change the background color only for the part of the text in a mermaid node

Tags: mermaid

I'm making a flow diagram where I need part of the text or its background to be of a different style. I tried to add `style` to the inside text, but it didn't work.

```
graph TD
    B --> C{Let <span style="background-color:#ddd">me</span> think}
```

Is it possible? Any recommendations?

The workaround that I'm thinking of is to have two blocks of different styles/backgrounds and removing the borderline according to this https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/flowchart.html#styling-a-node

```
graph TB
    subgraph block[" "]
    C[text1]
    D
    style C fill:blue,stroke-width:0px
    style D fill:yellow,stroke-width:0px
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

The only thing missing from your solution was the quotation marks.

You need to wrap your test with double quotes in order to [escape the special characters that break the syntax](https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/flowchart.html#special-characters-that-break-syntax).

Input:

```
graph TD
    B --> C{"Let <span style='background-color:#ddd'>me</span> think"}
```

[Output](https://mermaid.live/edit#pako:eNoljrsOgzAQBH_FuhQ0oPQWoUhSJlVSurn4jofANjLnAiH-PSbZarUarWYDG4hBQxdx7tX7brzKuaqqatRtM_BgUfUyo1eLrBNfig_asYsheapsmELUJyIqGsf1-cAaJf3gRwM7lOA4Ohwo32_HrwHp2bEBnStxi2kSA8YfKCYJr9Vb0BITl5BmQuH7gFnMgW5xWvLKNEiIz7_yz3z_AvqPQI0):

[image: mermaid live output]